# ¿Cómo puedo hacer realizar un salto de línea con lo que traigo de la base de datos?

Tags: php, html, mysql, jquery

Actualmente estoy intentando realizar un salto de linea según en lo que tengo en mi base de datos, un ejemplo es lo que representa la siguiente imagen:

[image: Varchar de la Base de Datos]

Como se puede ver en lo almacenado tiene saltos de línea.

¿es posible que pueda aplicar los salto de línea que están en la db en el siguiente código?

```
<p class="card-text">
    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row4['publicacion']); ?>
</p>
```

[image: Resultado del Codigo]

aclarando que en el **echo** tengo **htmlspecialchars()** que lo utilizo para evitar las etiquetas HTML.

Estaré atento a las respuestas, Gracias!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

he encontrado una solución a mi problema: es agregar`white-space: pre-line;` a la etiqueta donde esta el texto

```
<p class="card-text" style="white-space: pre-line;"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row4['publicacion']); ?></p>
```

ya que el texto se muestra como viene en la base de datos:

[image: Código HTML]

Ahora se muestra con los saltos de línea.
[image: Resultado]